# Find the IP address of the server which my MongoDB is deployed on

Tags: mongodb, parse-server

I have an own deployed MongoDB which is the database of my parse server. Parse server requires a `DATABASE_URI` and I pass `mongodb://user:password@mongodb:27017/main?authSource=admin&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1` to it and I'm able to save data from my android client to database. I've changed only the username and password than the real URI and the rest is exactly the same. But when I try to connect to my MongoDB from MongoDB Compass or similar tools, I get connection refused error. Since my parse server and my MongoDB are deployed on the same server, it seems that I should change the `mongodb` part of the `DATABASE_URI`, after @ and before : . But I can not find the correct subdomain or host name or `IP` address so I still get the connection refused error. My question is, is there a command to get the `IP` address of MongoDB server in MongoDB shell, or anything I can replace with the host name in URI?

Comment: If it's an "own deployed MongoDB", where did you deploy it? Also if you have access to its shell, how did you connect to it?

Comment: Actually not exactly own deployed. I use fandogh.cloud which is a hosting service and gives you a server. But starting a MongoDB service is something that is done by the fandogh.cloud itself. I mean I have not downloaded any MongoDB image. And also fandogh.cloud doesn't give me a clear URI. And also again fandogh.cloud enables a dashboard accessing to the database.

Comment: Read up on this issue: https://github.com/fandoghpaas/fandogh-cli/issues/171